# why least squares estimates are unbiased?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, variance, least-squares, parameter-estimation

I'm reading ESE (Element of Statistical Learning) and i'm struggling with this part:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KIxr.png)

My questions are:

1. why $ε$ is proportional to $ N(0,σ^2) $ ?
2. can you explain the second part of the text underlined in red? in particular, what is $l_i(x_0)$ and why it has been introduced?

Ty very much guys!

Comment: $\varepsilon$'s distribution is given by $N(0,\sigma^2)$. That is not a proportional symbol. To your second question, that's where you need to read more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't say that $\varepsilon_i$ is proportional to $\operatorname N(0,\sigma^2);$ rather it says that the probability distribution of $\varepsilon_i$ is $\operatorname N(0,\sigma^2).$ Thus the probability density function is a "bell-shaped" curve centered at $0,$ and the standard deviation, which is the distance from $0$ to either of the two inflection points of the curve, is $\sigma>0.$

Comment: Ok perfect! So the error is distributed like a bell shaped that has mean 0 and std-dev as sigma. 
And for the second part? Can you please explain me the meaning of introducing the $l$ terms?